# Unusual CSS Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an unusual CSS selection that I need to perform. I want to check if an input is requires, if it is, select its previous neighbour and do something to it (Which would be the label describing the input).

HTML Code

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>My Description</legend>
    <div>
        <input type="text" required="required">
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>My Description Two</legend>
    <div>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

How do I select the legends where there are inputs with the required attribute in their specific fieldset?

Comment: You can't. CSS cannot traverse up.

Comment: What do you mean by "select its previous neighbour"? Do you mean style the `<legend>` element?

Comment: Any special reason to put the `<input>` fields in a `<div>`?  Is this required? Also, can the `<legend>` element appear after the `<input>` field in the HTML mark-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would require CSS4 [subject](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) support — enabling you to prepend a `!` to any element in a selector chain which you desire to be returned — which sadly isn't currently available in any browser (and not likely to for a while). The method *would* be:

```
!legend + div > [required]
```

Without this, your options are quite obtuse. Assuming jQuery:

```
$( '[required]' ).parent().prev( 'legend' );
```

---

EDIT: Reading your post again, I realize the required input being nested in a div and the fact the previous element is a legend are just incidental details to explain your real problem, which is actually (unless I'm mistaken) about finding previous elements even if they're higher up the DOM tree — it just so happens I wrote a jQuery plugin for this, so it'd be stupid of me not to plug it here ;)

Using [jQuery.sequentialTraversal](https://github.com/barneycarroll/jquery.sequentialTraversal.js):

```
$( '[required]' ).sequentialPrev();
```

The plugin uses a 'flattened' interpretation of the document tree such that nesting becomes irrelevant, allowing you to travel up or down a purely sequential (as opposed to hierarchical) DOM list.

The methods available are `sequentialNext`, `sequentialNextAll`, `sequentialPrev` and `sequentialPrevAll` — which match the API for jQuery's `next`, 'nextAll', etc.

Comment: Sad indeed. I have to resort to using JavaScript but your answer was indeed the most helpful.

Comment: @ReidGarwin afraid so! Having said that, I just re-read your answer — my edit may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with CSS, but you can do it with JavaScript

Comment: "you can do it with JavaScript" Prove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this : `.prev()`

```
    var $this = $(this);
    var $previousLegend = $this.parent('div').prev();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/qB6f6/